# GuzzleHTTP Post request body contains query

Tags: php, laravel, post, guzzle

I'm trying to communicate with an external application (running Laravel) through GuzzleHTTP and the data gets posted and returned properly, but I'm getting my posted arguments back in the body reponse - which makes the json_decode() not work properly.

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix this? I can't really find anything about it nor in the docs of GuzzleHTTP or by Googling.

I guess using regex would work, but I'd like to use a less fragile method if possible.

The response I get back is as follows (encoded as json string):

> string(39) "aUnid%5B0%5D=20005&aUnid%5B1%5D=2008026"\n "hello"
>   As you can see it posts my arguments together with the result (which is "hello") in this case.

The code used to post the data is this :

```
$http = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => $baseUrl
]);

$uri = "/api/deliveries/read";
$response = $http->request("POST", $uri, [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer " . $accessToken,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ],
    GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::JSON => [
        'kmUnids' => [
            20005, 2008026
        ]
    ],
    'timeout' => 5
]);

echo $response->getBody();
```

The code used in the external application is as follows :

```
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @return JsonResponse
 */
public function getData (Request $request) : JsonResponse
{
    $request->validate([
        'kmUnids' => 'required|min:1|array'
    ]);
    /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedFieldInspection */
    $ids = $request->kmUnids;


    return \Response::json(
        "hello"
    );
}
```

Both applications are running Laravel (5.7) and using I'm using Laravel Passport for OAUTH2 communication.

Comment: For doing POST requests I would recommend you sticking to the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` and use it in combination with the `GuzzleHttp\Client::request` method.

Comment: When I use the `GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request` and send it with the `GuzzleClient\Client::send` command the server gets the request and processes it properly but when I execute the `getBody()` method it just gives me my defined body it should send. `kmUnids=...`. The `request()` method you told me to use doesn't accept a `Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface` as parameter.

Comment: I can solve the whole issue by using `explode("\n", (string) $response->getBody());` to seperate the query and result, but it just feels so dirty..

Comment: read carefully please, I did not tell you to use the `request` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should decode your return result like that:

$return_result= json_decode($response->getBody());
$data = $res->data;